# Koin - how to provide mock ViewModel for espresso test?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-espresso, android-viewmodel, koin

How can we inject mocked viewModel into Activity for espresso test?
Using `declareMock` I get mock object in Test class but Activity receives regular viewModel object.

```
@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4::class)
class SomeActivityTest : KoinTest {
    @Rule
    @JvmField
    val rule = ActivityTestRule(SomeActivity::class.java, true, true)
    val viewModel: MyViewModel by inject()

    @Before
    fun setup() {
        declareMock<MyViewModel>(isFactory = true, binds = listOf(ViewModel::class))
    }

    @After
    fun cleanUp() {
        stopKoin()
    }

    @Test
    fun shouldHaveTextViewVisible() {
        `when`(viewModel.sayHello())
                .thenReturn("hello view-model")
        onView(withId(R.id.tv_homescreen_message))
                .check(matches(isDisplayed()))
        onView(withId(R.id.tv_homescreen_message))
                .check(matches(withText("hello view-model")))
    }
}
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

In this case, Espresso test were still using main application class which declares all `koin` module required for app.

Starting `koin` without any modules, allows us to load only required modules during test.

```
// application class for espresso tests
class TestApp : Application() {
    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()
        startKoin(this, emptyList())
    }
}

class TestAppJUnitRunner : AndroidJUnitRunner() {
    override fun newApplication(cl: ClassLoader?, className: String?, context: Context?): Application {
        return super.newApplication(cl, TestApp::class.java.name, context)
    }
}

// app module build.gradle
android {
    defaultConfig {
        testInstrumentationRunner "com.package.TestAppJUnitRunner"
    }
}
```

It is important to declare mock method before starting activity

```
@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4::class)
class SomeActivityTest : KoinTest {
    @Rule
    @JvmField
    val rule = ActivityTestRule(SomeActivity::class.java, true, false)

    lateinit var mockVm: MyViewModel


    @Before
    fun setup() {
        mockVm = mock(MyViewModel::class.java)

        loadKoinModules(module {
            viewModel {
                mockVm
            }
        })
    }

    @After
    fun cleanUp() {
        stopKoin()
    }

    @Test
    fun shouldHaveTextViewWithMessage() {
        // 1. declare mock method
        val message = "hello view-model"
        Mockito.`when`(mockVm.sayHello())
                .thenReturn(message)

        // 2. start activity
        rule.launchActivity(null)


        // 3. test
        onView(withId(R.id.tv_message))
                .check(matches(isDisplayed()))

        onView(withId(R.id.tv_message))
                .check(matches(withText(message)))
    }
}
```

[Sample code](https://github.com/karadkar/PopularMovies-2/tree/dae33d771c25e1ac2921bfd92a89bd4e4f0490d0)

Comment: I received this : `Mockito cannot mock/spy because :
 - final class`

Comment: @miladsalimi I've annotated it with `@OpenForTesting`. check the source code I've shared.

Comment: How can i use this annotated ? with all-open compiler plugin?

Comment: Yes that'll do the trick @miladsalimi

Comment: Thanks , please see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69808166/donothing-does-not-work-when-i-want-to-mock-data-and-test-ui-fragment